# On hold post - then close and -ve votes points

Tags: discussion

My original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992783/c-sharp-named-pipes-is-this-the-way-to-go-for-my-situation) got placed on hold. 
Being new to posting I accept the question might have not been clear. 
I then corrected this but did not see any review post my updates and my post got closed. 
So not only did I not get to post, my votes got minused 2 * hold votes, i.e. 4 become 8. 
This does not seem fair, in that this was my first post placed on hold ?

Regards

Comment: The downvotes (-2 rep each, as is standard) aren't directly related to the close votes, and there's no way to tell which, if any, were cast by close-voters. (For what it's worth, I'm still unsure exactly what you're trying to do, so more clarification would not go amiss.)

Comment: DOwnvotes and close votes are cast based on the merits of the post, and nothing else.  That it was your first post in no way means that it is immune to criticism, or that it's somehow okay to ask an inappropriate question.

Answer (score 6):

#### The Good:

- No obvious spelling errors.
- Lots of information.

#### The Bad:

- The formatting is obscuring the information in the middle of significant noise.
- The question is buried in the body of the original... somewhere. Most people aren't going to spend a large amount of time reading to try to find it.

#### The Ugly:

- I can't really tell, even after 5 or 6 times reading through whether the suggestion below is actually what you're trying to ask.
- The ordering of information doesn't lend any coherence to the overall question.

If I understand what you're asking correctly, here's how I'd have written the question:

---

#### How do I use a named pipe for multiple connections in my client-server application?<sup>†</sup>

---

I'm writing a client-server application, and I need to pass information from the client to the server at regular intervals. For ease of use, and portability<sup>‡</sup> I'm using named pipes.

Ideally I'd like the server to wait for a connection, receive data, then resume waiting for the next connection. The client would function by connecting to the available pipe, and sending the data, and then disconnecting.

The client is meant to be short-lived, so I can't maintain a long term connection.

While trying to solve this problem, I wrote the following code to test pipes.

Client:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Client - simulate exe starting and ending
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", 
                                           "PipesOfPiece", 
                                           PipeDirection.Out,       
                                           PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
    client.Connect();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);

    Console.WriteLine("Client about to send message");
    writer.WriteLine("Called from client i = {0}", i);

    writer.Close();
    client.Close();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Server:

```
var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece", 
                                       PipeDirection.In);
server.WaitForConnection();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
while (true)
{
    // simulate start of poll code
    if (server.IsConnected)
    {
        if (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}", line);
        }
    } // End of poll code
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code, I only receive the first client message at the server.

What is causing the server to only receive the first message? Do I need to call `WaitForConnect` again? Finally, is the server code the owner of the pipe, that is, when the server application terminates, will the pipe be automatically closed?

---

[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)[named-pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-pipes)[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)

---

*<sup>†</sup> This title needs some work. It's too long, but after writing the body, I don't really have any good ideas left.*

*<sup>‡</sup> You'd want to add your own reasoning here. I just guessed.*

*I didn't suggest this edit to the original, because I have no clue if it actually is asking the question you intended to ask, and because I'm uncomfortable putting words into someone's mouth.*